# Django show error : "name 'dif_months_without_date' is not defined" though defined

Tags: django

I make the first django app and get error:
NameError: name 'get_date' is not defined
My structure:

- app

  - person

    - views.py
    - models.py
  - my_core

    - common.py

In common.py, i defined

```
def get_date():
    return "something"
```

When i call get_date() def in views.py, it is ok, but call it in models.py it show error.
In both views.py and models.py imported :

```
from my_core.common import *
```

What am i missing?
This is error in console:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 47, in inner
> response = get_response(request)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 181, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/first-app/app/person/views.py", line 228,
> in ajax_get_data
> 'person_status_list' : PERSON_STATUS   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py",
> line 61, in render
> return self.template.render(context)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 170, in render
> return self._render(context)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 162, in _render
> return self.nodelist.render(context)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 938, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 905, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py",
> line 315, in render
> return nodelist.render(context)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 938, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 905, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py",
> line 214, in render
> nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 905, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 988, in render
> output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 671, in resolve
> obj = self.var.resolve(context)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 796, in resolve
> value = self._resolve_lookup(context)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 837, in _resolve_lookup
> current = getattr(current, bit)   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/first-app/app/person/models.py", line 87,
> in continue_months
> return get_date() NameError: name 'get_date' is not defined

Comment: Why does the title say `dif_months_without_date`, and not `get_date`?

Comment: Sry, i have just update my question.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question and the relevant section(s) of the file that is triggering the error

Comment: @ Iain Shelvington I have just added error in console.

Comment: I optimized my code, error will disappear when calling common.get_date()
so please help me close this question. Thanks all!